# Download image from angular js

Tags: angularjs, web

I am getting image from the MongoDB . Now i want to download the image to my system through code.

From this code i am getting the object :
     $scope.clickEvent = function(x) {

```
             var path = x.path.replace('uploads','');
             $http({
             method: 'GET',
                    url: $API_URL + path,
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": $localStorage.currentUser.token
                    }
                }).then(function (response) {



                 var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/Image'});
                    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    window.open(fileURL);

                    console.log("Result: " + response.data);


                });
            };
```

Bt the thing i am getting download is:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding the `content-type` header and the `responseType` to 'blob'

```
$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: $API_URL + path,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpg', //content type set to image
        'Authorization': $localStorage.currentUser.token
      },
      responseType: 'blob' 
    })
```

Comment: got the answer. Thanks.